# Выдаёт ошибку при попытке реализовать Router в React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

У меня есть функция

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about">
        <Posts />
      </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> A  is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>`

Comment: У меня есть:
import React from 'react';

const About = () => {
    return (
        <h1>
            Это приложение создано в качестве обуч. ролика на ULBI TV
        </h1>
    );
};

export default About;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция роута должна выглядеть так

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Все ваши `Route` должны быть обернуты в `<Routes>`, а компоненты, которые должны отображаться необходимо указывать в element.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Просто в обучающем ролике оно по-другому выглядело

Comment: @Danoslo255 Возможно ролик древний и используется старая версия react-dom-routers.